# jQuery on click gives value of PREVIOUSLY checked radio button

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I am new to jQ (as my code evidences). Sanity check please. (Yes there are lots of jQuery/radio threads here but could not see this problem coming up elsewhere - suspect it is my poor jQ).

HTML:

```
<div class="row colFlush">
<div class="col-xs-8 colFlush">
    <label for="numberOfTimesADayFixed"> Number of times a day <i class="explain fa fa-question-circle text-primary" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" tabindex="0" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?"></i></label>

    <div class="btn-group-xs smhRadio" role="group" name="numberOfTimesADayFixed"
         data-toggle="buttons" id="numberOfTimesADayFixed">

        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="fixedTimesPerDay"/> 1
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>
            <input type="radio" value="2" checked="checked" name="fixedTimesPerDay"/> 2
        </label>

                  etc...


        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>
            <input type="radio" value="8" name="fixedTimesPerDay"/> 8
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

jQ (forgive the mess):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//        CHANGE 2 ids 2 ids!!!!!
    $("#numberOfTimesADayFixed .btn").on('click', function () {
        ToggleRadioButtons("#numberOfTimesADayFixed", $(this));
     var $timesNeeded = $("#numberOfTimesADayFixed input[type='radio']:checked").attr("value");console.log($timesNeeded)
    });
});
```

Basically if I click on 2 then 3 I get 2 as the returned value. I then click on 5 and I get the 3 etc. IE I get the PREVIOUS click's value.

As you can see from my code I am struggling with jQ but have built a complicated page which is behaving just as I want.

(See "Times settings -> Multiple fixed time" at http://www.moviemaui.com/sane30/beta31/newBuildRand16SundayBeforePop.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution to change `click` to `change`. Presumably the `click` checks for the current state BEFORE any change has taken place. (Change in uppercase just for emphasis.)

```
$("#numberOfTimesADayFixed .btn").on('CHANGE', function () {
```

ADVICE PLEASE. Should I leave this up? If I had found this answer earlier I would have saved myself an hour of head scratching but then maybe most people know this problem.

Not sure of the etiquette of this situation.